# Skipping certain items in PlotLegend

Tags: plotting

I've the following code:

```
Clear[a, x, f, g, tabf1, tabf2, tabf3, tabg1, tabg2, tabg3];
f[a_, x_] = Sin[a*x];
g[a_, x_] = Cos[a*x];
tabf1 = Table[{x, f[1, x]}, {x, -π, π, π/12}];
tabf2 = Table[{x, f[2, x]}, {x, -π, π, π/12}];
tabg1 = Table[{x, g[1, x]}, {x, -π, π, π/12}];
tabg2 = Table[{x, g[2, x]}, {x, -π, π, π/12}];

Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ListLinePlot[
  {tabf1, tabf2, tabg1, tabg2},
  PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Red, Dashed}, {Blue}, {Blue, Dashed}},
  Frame -> True, PlotLegend -> {"f1", "f2", "g1", "g2"},
  LegendPosition -> {1.2, -0.3}, LegendShadow -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are four curves in my plotting. I want to display legend for only `f1` and `g1`. How do I skip `f2` and `g2` from it?

Comment: Unless you have a very old version of Mathematica it is best not to use the `PlotLegends` package. It has been superceded by built in options for `Graphics` functions

Answer (score 5):

```
ListLinePlot[{tabf1, tabf2, tabg1, tabg2},
 PlotLegends -> Framed@LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"tabf1", "tabg1"}],
 PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Red, Dashed}, {Blue}, {Blue, Dashed}},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

With the now obsolete `PlotLegends` package you would have to use `ShowLegend`:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

ShowLegend[
 ListLinePlot[{tabf1, tabf2, tabg1, tabg2},
  PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Red, Dashed}, {Blue}, {Blue, Dashed}},
  ImageSize -> 600,
  Frame -> True],
 {{
   {Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], "tabf1"},
   {Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}], "tabg1"}
   },
  LegendShadow -> None,
  LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it answers my question. Is there a way to do the same with PlotLegend instead of PlotLegends?

Comment: See update of answer